# How to get/set value from custom collection in this case in Magento

Tags: php, arrays, magento

In my custom module controller i have a situation to create function with posted attributes

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$details = Mage::getModel('custom/custom')->load($params['id']);
```

`$params` array will looks like this

```
Array
(
    [product_id] => 3
    [id] => 82
    [value] => 20
)
```

`$params['value']` is one of my column name in the below array

`$details` array will looks like this

```
Array
(
    [id] => 82
    [18] => 1
    [18_price] => 100.000
    [19] => 4
    [19_price] => 200.000
    [20] => 5
    [20_price] => 100.000
    [21] => 8
    [21_price] => 200.000
    [22] => 0
    [22_price] => 0.000
    .
    .
    .
    .
    [product_id] => 3
)
```

If i use `$details->get20()` i will get the value of `$details['20']` from the above array, i.e, 5,

Every time i can't use this standard function like `$details->get20()`,`$details->get21()`,`$details->get22()` because i am going to have 20 to 30 columns like this, so i want to create this function using `$params['value']` and this is not only for get method again i have to set the value in same place after few lines of my logic.

for this i tried the following ways

```
$details->get.''.$params['value']();
$details->get.$params['value']();
```

But no use it is giving **Fatal error: Call to undefined function 20()**

How can i achieve this in my case ?

Comment: And i will get only integers like 18, 19, 20, 21... as $params['value']

Answer (score 0):

You must set a variable as the function name before trying to call it:

```
$function = 'get' . $params['value'];

$details->$function();
```

Or you can do it like:

```
$details->{'get' . $params['value']}();
```